# variable binding to pattern in case clause in scala match expression

Tags: scala, case-class

I created an object for demonstrating use of use of case class as:

```
object MatchWithPattern extends App
{
    case class Person(firstName:String,lastName:String);
    def whatYouGaveMe(obj:Any):String={
                obj match {
                case str : String => s"you gave me a String ${str}";
                case person : Person(firstName,lastName) => s" You gave me a Person Object with ${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}";
                case default => "You gave me a Any class Object";
                }

        }

    var person= new Person("Mukesh", "Saini");
    Console.println(whatYouGaveMe(person));
}
```

and code does not compile and gives the error

**error: '=>' expected but '(' found**

Now I change following

```
case person : Person(firstName,lastName) => s" You gave me a Person Object with ${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}";
```

to

```
case person @ Person(firstName,lastName) => s" You gave me a Person Object with ${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}";
```

code compiles and runs successfully.

Now I changes

```
case str : String => s"you gave me a String ${str}";
```

to

```
case str @ String => s"you gave me a String ${str}";
```

and it gives me an error as :

**error: object java.lang.String is not a value**

The same case is true for

```
case list : List(1,_*) // gives error

case list @ List(1,_*) // run successfully
```

So my question is that where should I use **@** instead of **:**

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The colon is used to match against the *type*, the `@` is used to perform a recursive pattern match via the `unapply` method of the thing on the right-hand side.

In your examples, `String` is a type, but `Person(x,y)` and `List(1,_*)` are not.

Comment: : I am new to Scala so if you will provide more details it will be helpful for me to understand it more clearly

Comment: Crystal clear after adding second line as :String is a type, but Person(x,y) and List(1,_*)